# Weekly Changing Label in Storyboard

Tags: swift, storyboard

As part of a class project I'm using Swift Storyboard to create a pregnancy app and was thinking of adding a label onto the homepage that displays the week of pregnancy you are up to based on a user input that changes each week as a tracking sort of feature.

How would I go about adding this? Would it be easier as an Iboutlet or a whole new class as a function?
And if so how could this be done?
The Label in question is 'Week Label'
[image: Label]

Comment: I would suggest an IBOutlet. The reason is it would be simple to handle

Comment: How would I do that? I still need a solution

Comment: Its depend on your label data. If you will need to change label value on background thread then use class or on otherside IBoutlet is perfect for Storyboard!